# Which method is better always writing data with file_put_contents or check if data changed and then update file?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so I was wondering which one of these 2 methods is better ?

Method 1: query string from database, and directly use file_put_contents()

Method 2: query string from database, use file_get_contents, check if both data are identical from the db and from the file and if not use file_put_contents()

Just want to know which one is a better method for a file that is a main file required for page display on the site ?

and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1 will be better if the string changes a lot.

Method 2 will be better if the string doesn't change that often.

It has to do with the fact that reading is faster than writing.

You could consider putting a value in the database which says if the string content is already saved, if not:

- Save it
- Update the database saying it has saved.

Answer (score 2):

Method 1 is better if the string changes everytime.

If the ratio of changes to database queries becomes less, it can not be specifically said.

Method 2 is then clearly better if the string never changes.

Generally it's faster to read from a file than to save from it. At which stage this pays off for your computer with it's hard and software, you need to metric that to make an educated guess.